# How to reconcile rootless podman and buildah config-s, containers and images

Tags: container, podman, buildah

My aim is to have `podman` and `buildah` working together locally on my PC: "rootless"  with *low-friction*.  I don't expect things to be *perfect* or *seamless* yet.  The basis of my questions relate to this on-line tutorial and how-to page:

1. [Everything You Need to Know About Buildah](https://appfleet.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-buildah/) (appfleet, 2020-05-18, accessed: today)
2. [Basic Setup and Use of Podman in a Rootless environment](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/docs/tutorials/rootless_tutorial.md) (podman)

I have installed ...

- buildah version => v**1.16.4** (image-spec 1.0.1-dev, runtime-spec 1.0.2-dev)
- podman version => v**2.1.1**
- O/S => Ubuntu v20.04

I completed the `buildah` stage successfully, up to step 12 ("lists your Buildah images").  When I moved-on, the next stage; "**Running Your Buildah Image with Podman**" I hit a snag.  Part of the *snag* seems to be that `buildah` and `podman` '*should*' supposed to work smoothly these days.

Listing my local (rootless)  `podman` list of images:

```
$ podman images list
REPOSITORY  TAG     IMAGE ID  CREATED  SIZE
$ 
$ podman  ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE   COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS   NAMES
```

While `buildah` shows the anticipated result:

```
$ buildah list
CONTAINER ID  BUILDER  IMAGE ID     IMAGE NAME                       CONTAINER NAME
ebb9436a6c76     *                  scratch                          working-container
38186baf1438     *     a24bb4013296 docker.io/library/alpine:latest  alpine-container
```

My first thought is that there is a mismatch (by default) between `podman` config and the `buildah`.  I am running a rootless set-up, using the VFS overlay as recommended. My local config files only have comments -- No values were set.

```
$ ls -l  ~/.config/containers/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  2 will wrk 4096 Sep 23 01:15 ./
drwx------ 83 will wrk 4096 Oct 31 01:30 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 will wrk 1207 Aug 31 12:13 containers.conf
-rw-rw-r--  1 will wrk  788 Aug 31 13:09 storage.conf
```

The `buildah info` command tells me that my images are at:

```
/home/will/.local/share/containers/storage
```

Then, looking over [Podman in a Rootless environment](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/docs/tutorials/rootless_tutorial.md) (podman) seems that I must change the runtime to `crun` -- Fair enough.

*And yet*, even after this config change, the `podman info` from command line -- The output says:

```
ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: 'cri-o-runc: /usr/lib/cri-o-runc/sbin/runc'
    path: /usr/lib/cri-o-runc/sbin/runc
    version: 'runc version spec: 1.0.2-dev'
os: linux
```

Meaning for one, that it has not recognised a change to rootless mode.  `crun` exists on this PC, as: `/usr/bin/crun`.

Other `podman` settings seem odd or ambiguous scrolling through the `podman info` output.  May be I'm looking at teh wrong command.  Also, `podman info`  is reporting **cgroups v1**.  Rootless activity needs cgroups v2 as I understand it.

I believe that what I'm looking for is a walkthrough or manual page showing me HOW to set-up a minimal set of local config files under:

```
ls -l  ~/.config/containers/*
```

for `podman` and `buildah` in the rootless mode.  I'm convinced it is practical.  Just want to find the place/places that can show me how.

Comment: `crun`? Did you mean `runc`?

Comment: I want to run containers rootless.  So far the rootless information I have read says to use `crun` and to set-up everything in  `$HOME/.config/containers` -- I began with the system settings; reportedly they do not work for rootless configurations.  I do not want applications under test to have any root access.

Comment: We don't really need a `rootless` tag. That's just a property of the container setup, it doesn't merit much of anything by itself.

Comment: I have to disagree.  Docker for example runs with/needs root access and some snaps can have(need) root as well as different apps and scripts.  I believet it is helpful to identify things you can do without `root` or `sudo` requirements -- Just me, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

What is your PC OS?, they should work seamlessly together.
Why do you have containers.conf and storage.conf in your homedir?  These should only be there if you are changing config, most users would not have these files there but would use the system defaults.